# How to design animated moving object when scrolling in WordPress website?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-animations

I'm new to WordPress and want to design a landing website with WordPress. How do achieve the scrolling effect when a user scrolling the website and wants to move an animated object through the website?
[image: This is a sample picture of web site]

I want to move the airplane when scrolling with the dash line path and hide in the last section airplane come and start again at the end of that section. Please Help to achieve this design. Please give a source to refer to this kind of design.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [gsap](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/) with the `scrollTrigger` property.

Sample: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNOBLBV